# Button being cast to a checkbox for some strange reason?

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android, android-xml

I'm trying to get 2 columns of checkboxes (not with a table-layout) with a button at the bottom of each row.  Trouble is that when i do this the button (in the first column) looks like it is being typecasted to a checkbox automatically.  However, when i put the button in the second column, nothing bad seems to happen.  Its the first column that is giving me problems

The setup below doesn't crash (although both buttons would be in the second column instead of one in each column,  which of course is not what i want).

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1.7"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:background="@drawable/table_layout_bg" 
       >


         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/American_chkBX"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/Asian_chkBX"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/BarPub_chkBX"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/Breakfast_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/Desert_chkBX"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/FastFood_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/Healthy_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/Italian_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/Mexican_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/SeaFood_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>   

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/select_none_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/select_none"
                />  

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/select_all_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/select_all"
                />
            </LinearLayout>



     </LinearLayout>
```

This alternate setup crashes the app with the error log shown below (it seems like the button is being type cast as a check-box without me trying??).  I find this error really odd and wanted to know if there is a fundamental piece of android/xml/UI that i don't understand that makes this happen.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1.7"
       android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
       android:background="@drawable/table_layout_bg" 
       >

   <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp">

            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/A_chkBX"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/B_chkBX"     android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/C_chkBX"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/D_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/E_chkBX"    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/select_all_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/select_all"
                />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp">

            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/A1_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/B1_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/C1_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/D1_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
            <CheckBox android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/E1_chkBX" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>    

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/select_none_btn"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/select_none"
                />  
            </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

And here are the relevant logs that are generated:

```
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dumbasssoftware/com.dumbasssoftware.mainstuff.PickerViewActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at com.dumbasssoftware.mainstuff.PickerViewActivity.onCreate(PickerViewActivity.java:708)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
03-26 22:21:30.279: E/AndroidRuntime(1473):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: I sometimes get similar errors when I change layout XML's in a way that I replace one widget type with another with the same ID. Clean & rebuild is a fix for me.

Comment: That did it. I'm usually very good about rebuilding but I guess this time i didnt think to rebuild after cutting and pasting 5 line of code. post this answer (maybe you can also give some explanation of why a rebuild is needed for XML changes) and ill accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped. I've posted the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can occur when changing layout XML files in a way that some widget keeps it's ID, but changes type (class).

My guess is that `R` class is not being correctly, automatically rebuilt by Eclipse/Android plugin.

Fix is to manually force project clean & rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

use "import com.rey.material.widget.CheckBox;"
instead of "import android.widget.CheckBox;" it worked for me